# Android: How to "Voice Detecting" to Voice Recorder

Tags: android

I've done voice recording and playing following this link:

[Record audio and play the recorded audio](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html#capture)

I need a change in it. It is recording and playing on button click. Rather I want to a background service or whatever that continuously "listening mic", if it detects some voice then it should record it (let say max length of recording is 1 min) and on voice recording finishing (either there is no input or 1 min recording completes) then it should play it automatically.

Kindly, guide me to achieve it...

Thanks,

Comment: does anyone know about it? I found this functionality in may application like **Talking Tom Cat**, you can find it here [link](http://www.appbrain.com/app/talking-tom-cat-free/com.outfit7.talkingtom). **Tom Cat** itself finds that you are talking in the mic and records your voice and then play it... I need to do the same... Thanks

Comment: I am also searching for the same thing if u get it means let me know...

Comment: Hey MudasserHassan and @Taruni I need to detect user's voice and show the error if user muted himself for N seconds then I need to alert the user.